# Making the controller extend with the amount of text in UILabel in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm quite new to Swift and iOS. I'm working on just getting things working so ignore the terrible UI. At the moment my text runs off the screen of the controller and I would like it make it so that depending on how long the text is the controller will allow for scrolling to accommodate it.

How can I do this with Swift and iOS?

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: you can put all your views on the screen into a `UIScrollView` and update its `contentSize` to enable scrolling once all the frames are set. You can do that preferably in `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did put everything into the `UIScrollView` and it seems to all work without updating the `contentSize` and `viewDidAppear`. What would be the benefits/ reasons to be using `contentSize` and `viewDidAppear` within the code? @ozgur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should place all your subviews (UILabel, UIImage etc.) in a `UIScrollView`.

Then, you have two options:

- **Springs & Struts**: Once the frames of all subviews are set you can update the scroll view's `contentSize` property so it allows you to scroll. You can do this preferably in `viewDidAppear` method as all the frames have their exact value in there:

  ```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: bottomLabel.frame.maxY)
  }
  ```
- **AutoLayout**: With Autolayout, you no longer need to set the `contentSize` property explicitly. Just make sure you set vertical and width constraints correctly so AutoLayout will infer the contentSize automatically. Your subviews inside scrollView should be laid out as follows:

  ```
     Scroll View
  ----------------
  |   Top Label  |
  | ------------ | v:10pt
  |              |
  |     Image    | image.width = view.width
  |              |
  | ------------ | v:10pt
  | Bottom Label |
  ----------------
  ```

You can download the [test project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zlkh7x3qzqlmqvz/AABGLY60o0C4rFBrpqEW_Q0pa?dl=0) and see the constraints I set in the Interface Builder.

Here is the result I got:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! That totally makes sense. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Put everything you want to scroll inside of a [UIScrollView](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122139/uiscrollview-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you! Putting everything into the UIScrollView did work perfectly!